# User management on jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am creating a JHipster application, in which user management is required.
I have made the relationships with entity and they are working perfectly, I just have 2 questions:

-When I am creating a new Entity and it comes to the step I have to fill the fiels, there is a field named "user" and you can choose on which user it will be saved. How can i get rid of it, so it always save the exact entry on the specific user ? I have made a many-to-one relationship with each entity and as displayed field I have chosen "login".

-When signed in as Admin, under User Management in menu, is it possible for the admin to perform CRUD operations over users? Do I have to create relationship over admin-user ?

Answer (score 1):

1.You can edit User.java Entity and do modifications on the code.

2.On the newest version You have user management on admin:admin user out of the box :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will play around with User.java.

Comment: Haven't done any improvement on this. Any specific suggestions ?

Comment: Please update JHipster. On the newest version You have user management on admin:admin user out of the box :)